# NGINX URL with argument rewrite to URL without argument

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have an NGINX background on my server. I cannot figure out why my rules doesn't work.

How can I redirect or rewrite it so I could open URL with the same content, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/my_dir/value/
```

If I have this URL, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/my_dir/filename.php?parameter=value
```

I tried some solutions but they didn't worked:

```
Case #1:
location /my_dir/ {
  if ($args ~* "filename.php/?parameter=value1") {
      rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/my_dir/$arg_param1? last;
  }
}

Case #2:
rewrite ^/my_dir/(.*)$ /filename.php?parameter=$1 last;

Case #3:
location /my_dir {
    try_files $uri $uri/ my_dir/filename.php?$args;
}

Case #4:
location /my_dir/ {
    rewrite ^/my_dir/filename.php?parameter=(-+([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))?\$ /filename.php?parameter=$1 last;
}
```

Do I have to configure my PHP file for get it working?
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
location / {

    rewrite ^/my_dir/filename.php?parameter=(.*)/$ /my_dir/$1/ permanent;
}
```

Or:

```
location /my_dir {

    rewrite ^/filename.php?parameter=(.*)/$ /$1/ permanent;
}
```